# Can I use a Quarz Oszilator instead of a Standard quartz?

Tags: oscillator

I want to complete this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX0P8B3pk7g) on burning a bootloader onto a atmega328. There a Standard quartz is used, but called a Quarz oszilator. Now I bought this [Oszilator](http://www.reichelt.de/Oszillatoren/OSZI-16-000000/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=3174&ARTICLE=13686&OFFSET=500&SID=15Vts35awQATcAAIkWztIb2cde2c9d208872274bd47399b9e528b&LANGUAGE=EN). Can I use the oszilator as well and how can I connect it?

Comment: in other words can I somehow use this [guy](http://www.reichelt.de/Oszillatoren/OSZI-16-000000/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=3174&ARTICLE=13686&OFFSET=500&SID=15Vts35awQATcAAIkWztIb2cde2c9d208872274bd47399b9e528b&LANGUAGE=EN) instead of this [guy](http://www.reichelt.de/Quarze/16-0000-HC49U-S/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=3173&ARTICLE=32852&OFFSET=500&SID=15Vts35awQATcAAIkWztIb2cde2c9d208872274bd47399b9e528b&LANGUAGE=EN) or must I buy the standart quarz

Comment: While Botnic has given a good answer, it's worth pointing out that you don't actually need any oscillator at all: the ATmega328 has an internal 8MHz RC oscillator, and the Arduino IDE offers a bootloader that configures the clock as such.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't watch the video.

But normally it is not be a problem to connect the oscillator to one of the XTAL pins (only one of them will work. Read the datasheet). You will need to set the Clock Option Select to External Clock.

[image]

Comment: acording to datasheet there are the pins: NC/Enable, GND, Output and +vcc. Can you explain please wich one i could use. [Data Sheet](http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/B400/OSZI.pdf) (I have no idea how oszilator work)

Comment: The "Output" will carry the signal. GND and VCC are power and the enable allows you to shut down the device. You need to connect the output to the Atmegas XTAL pin